# getting the number of records of a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Quick question - this is literally pulling my hair out (whats left of it).

Here is the sql query :

```
        $getRecords = "SELECT * FROM events";
        $findRecords = mysql_query($getRecords, $dbhandle);
        $count = mysql_num_rows($findResults);
        echo "<p>Showing $count Event(s)</p>";
```

I get this returned back

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given

I have other sql queries after this and they all work fine - even in previous websites I have used this formula and its always worked but on this project its knocking me back

Thanks in advance to any light you can shine on this

Eric

Comment: Try using `$dbhandle` instead of `$findResults` for `mysql_num_rows`

Comment: `mysql_num_rows` uses the resultset, not the database handle.

Comment: In case your query results are very large, you may want to find out the result size in the query itself: `select count(*) as num_rows from events`.  Once the query is executed, you can figure out your pagination stuff, then issue a query for the data.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($findResults);
```

To

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($findRecords);
```

Answer (score 0):

$findResult is not set, so it is null.

```
$getRecords = "SELECT * FROM events";
$findRecords = mysql_query($getRecords, $dbhandle);
$count = mysql_num_rows($findRecords);
echo "<p>Showing $count Event(s)</p>";
```

Also, you should not use mysql_* functions as they are deprecated. It is just as easy to switch to mysqli or pdo.

Answer (score 0):

If `mysql_num_rows($findResults)` returns `false`, it is because your request has gone wrong...

Change `mysql_num_rows($findResults)` by `mysql_num_rows($findRecords)`...